# Remove a given element from the other set in a dict of two sets

Tags: python, dictionary, set

I have a dict, `{ "foo": set(["a", "b"]), "bar": set(["c", "d"]) }`, and I'm given an element of one of the two sets and the name of the *other* set. I need to remove that element. How would I go about doing this? My best attempt so far is this:

```
keys = dict.keys()
if Element in dict[keys[0]].union(dict[keys[1]]):
  dict[keys[abs(keys.index(Other_Set) - 1)]].remove(Element)
```

This seems to be a bit excessive, though; is there any way I can improve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
dictionary['foo' if otherset == 'bar' else 'bar'].discard(element)
```

Comment: I like this best. I would just replace remove with discard as Matthew pointed out.

Comment: @Plumenator, yep, realized that would be better immediately after. :-)

Comment: Since the keys ('foo' and 'bar') are user-inputted, this won't look quite as pretty once implemented, but I like it nonetheless. Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use a dictionary to look up the other set:

```
>>> other={'foo':'bar','bar':'foo'}
>>> d = { "foo": set(["a", "b"]), "bar": set(["b", "c"]) }
>>> element = "b"
>>> setname = "bar"
>>> d[other[setname]].discard(element)
>>> d
{'foo': set(['a']), 'bar': set(['c', 'b'])}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
keys = dict.keys()
dict[keys[1 - keys.index(Other_Set)]].discard(Element)
```

With `discard`, you don't get a `KeyError` if the element's not in the set.  Thus, you don't need your check (another alternative is to just ignore the `KeyError`).  And `1 -` removes the need for the `abs`.

Answer (score 1):

This one might suit you if you do not know a priori the names of the keys in `dct`:

```
dct={ "foo": set(["a", "b"]), "bar": set(["c", "d"]) }

element='b'
other_set='bar'

for key,value in dct.iteritems():
    if key != other_set:
        value.discard(element)

print(dct)
# {'foo': set(['a']), 'bar': set(['c', 'd'])}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
element = "b"
other = "bar"
d = { "foo": set(["a", "b"]), "bar": set(["b", "c"]) }
theSet = d[[s for s in d.iterkeys() if s != other][0]]
theSet.discard(element)
```

Answer (score 0):

My variation, generic for any number of sets, takes out given item for all the others:

```
dict_of_sets={'foo':set(['a','b','c']),'bar': set(['d','b','e']),'onemore': set(['a','e','b'])}
givenset,givenitem='bar','b'
otherset= (key for key in dict_of_sets if key != givenset)
for setname in otherset:
  dict_of_sets[setname].discard(givenitem)

print dict_of_sets

"""Output:
{'foo': set(['c', 'a']), 'bar': set(['e', 'b', 'd']), 'onemore': set(['e', 'a'])}
"""
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a much more "pythonic" way:

```
>>> d = { "foo": set(["a", "b"]), "bar": set(["b", "c"]) }

>>> d['foo']-=d['bar']
>>> d
{'foo': set(['a']), 'bar': set(['c', 'b'])}
```

Of course `d['foo']` could be `d[hashable_key]` with hashable_key having user input or what have you.

[Recall that the operators](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set) `- & ^ |` on sets are overloaded to the respective mutating methods of:

```
a_set.difference_update(other_set) # also "-"
a_set.intersection_update(other_set) # also "&"
a_set.symmetric_difference_update(other_set) # also "^"
a_set.update(other_set) # also "-"
```

You can then use augmented assignment `-=` to modify the set value of 'foo' in place. All these other solutions offered here seem -- too wordy to me.

**Edit** I misread the OP, and ignore this as an answer. I voted up [the best solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368613/remove-a-given-element-from-the-other-set-in-a-dict-of-two-sets/3368649#3368649).

Comment: @Plumenator: I misread the OP and focused on the result being the differences between the sets. Sorry...